# How do i reference correctly to a "grandparent" object in c# entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to create a relational database with objects that have references to their parents and their grandparents. How do i do this?

For example i have these 3 objects:

1. A tree, with multiple branches
2. A branch, with multiple leafs
3. A leaf, with multiple insects
4. An insect

Now i want:

1. A branch to have a reference to its tree
2. A leaf to have a reference to its branch and its tree
3. An insect to have a reference to its leaf, its branch and its tree

How do i set this up in the entity framework?

I tried the following:

```
class Tree {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<Branch> Branches {get;set;}
}

class Branch {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<Leaf> Leafs {get;set;}

    public int TreeId {get;set;}
    public Tree Tree {get;set;}
}

class Leaf {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<Insect> Insects {get;set;}

    public int BranchId {get;set;}
    public int Branch Branch {get;set;}
    public int TreeId {get;set;}
    public Tree Tree {get;set;}
}

class Insect {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    
    public int LeafId {get;set;}
    public Leaf Leaf {get;set;}
    public int BranchId {get;set;}
    public int Branch Branch {get;set;}
    public int TreeId {get;set;}
    public Tree Tree {get;set;}
}
```

I think i have to do something in the OnModelCreating method in the Database context, i tried this, but it did not seem to work:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tree>()
            .HasMany<Leaf>()
            .WithOne(l => l.Tree)
            .HasForeignKey(l => l.TreeId);
```

Please help

Comment: Are you familiar with [`HierarchyId`](https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId) ?